# Android Smack MUC 400 Bad Request sending group Chat Message

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack

Hey i am developing Chat Application using XMPP Smack Library. Recently i am working on Group Chat While sending Group message some message will be drop so receiver wouldn't receives message from the sender side. it will gives me 400 bad request.

it is working sometimes. and sometimes not work

here i found this kind of message in 400 bad request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message to="156@abc.com/Android" id="nXlV6-1144" type="error" from="24@confrence.abc.com/156@abc.com.com">
   <received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="nXlV6-1142" />
   <error code="400" type="modify">
      <bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" />
   </error>
</message>
```

if successfully send message it will give this kind of message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message to="156@abc.com/Android" id="nXlV6-1411" type="groupchat" from="24@conference.abc.com/156@abc.com">
   <body>eyu4u4</body>
   <chatDetail xmlns="jabber:x:oob">
      <UID>156</UID>
      <time>04:20 PM</time>
      <user_icon>24_group_icon.jpg</user_icon>
      <SentTime>1474368652960</SentTime>
      <USERName>vasudev89</USERName>
      <user_name>cryan</user_name>
      <message>eyu4u4</message>
      <type>group</type>
      <phone_number>24</phone_number>
   </chatDetail>
   <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" />
</message>
```

how i can send message persistently? Any idea?
Thank You in Advance.

here is my code sending muc message:

```
public boolean sendGroupMessage(Message message, String strGroupID) {

            DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(message);
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "sendGroupMessage");
                //Log.i("JOIN MUC","To join group chat: " + groupChat.getClassId());

                // Get the MultiUserChatManager
                MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(AbstractXMPPConnection);

                // Create a MultiUserChat using an XMPPConnection for a room
                MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(strGroupID + AppWSConstants.XMPP_JID_GROUP_CHAT_SUFFIX);
                muc.sendMessage(message);
                return true;
            } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

@LearnPainLess, follow these steps to solve group chat issue

-when creating groups, save the jid of group in the database, like "somegroup@conference.{domain}.com"

-create background task for creating xmpp connection (this way it will always be connected)

-after logging in to xmpp, get the group names from the database and connect to them

also, in openfire, Group Chat > Group Chat Settings > Edit Icon > Default Room Settings > Check "Make Room Persistant"

also, in other settings > Never kick idle users

Comment: Thank you it works. but my messages are not receiving to any user.

Comment: also go to openfire > Server Settings Tab > Offline Messages (left menu) > Check Store, Store or Drop ( and set the maximum size for each user)

after doing this, also did you setup packet listener or stanza listener for receiving packets

Comment: thanks for your help. :) can you please upload working demo of group chat?
this will be very helpful for me.

Comment: and which version of smack is better? currently i moved from 4.0.6 to 4.1.8

Comment: i am using 4.1.0.. ya sure.. i will share my xmpp base class and one small demo.. but tomorrow, as i am the only one left in the office :p ..mail me at zainullahdev@outlook.com and i will reply back

Comment: hello @zain ullah, i tried what u suggested to modify on OpenFire server, but my chat group still delete after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on "seen and delivered" in MUC and facing with this issue when replying back with the same packet id, still testing but I think in your case you should move your xmpp connection to background service and after connecting to xmpp on device launch up, connect to all the muc in your database. This way you will always be connected to groups.

**cause :** according to me, when the other user is not connected to the muc and you send a message or when you reply to the group with the same packet id.

**Note:** I am using multiuserchat.sendmessage to send group message and chat.sendmessage to send message to single user

**SMACK 4.1**

** update **

I fixed it by creating new packet instead of modifying the one i am receiving

here is the packet

```
Message msgg = new Message();
msgg.setBody(message.getPacketID());
msgg.setSubject(MessageModel.CHAT_STATUS_SEEN + "");
XmppBase.sendMUCChatMsg(msgg);
```

in your case, try with simple packet first. if all works well, then add extension one by one and see where you get the error, Thanks

Comment: HI I think it is same packet issue but still i am confirm updating   with snip code of multi user send message...   i have also problem with connection it is  disconnect many times

Comment: I had the disconnection problem, but when i moved it to background service it was fixed. 

also one more thing, if you are using openfire server, enable archiving chat, and there see if the user is getting disconnected after you send a message "bad request"

also you should send group messages using yourmuc.sendmessage and not chat.sendmessage. 

Note : dont specify **TO** or **FROM** when sending message

Comment: I see from the snip code that you are first connecting to muc and then sending message. So for next message, it will reconnect you and then try to send message.

seperate these two logics : 

when opening the chat window check if multiuserchat is null, if yes connect to muc using getMultiUserChat()

I will add another answer with my code

Comment: I am also updating my background service code that makes you more understanding where i have mistake

Answer (score 0):

I have an XmppBase class where i put all my xmpp code

All listeners in seperate folder

Connection is stored in static variable and i retrive it using

Utils.getConnection()

```
// this function m calling from background service and everywhere if not connectect to xmpp
public static XMPPConnection CreateXmppConnection() {
    if (Utils.getConnection() == null) {
        try {
            Boolean isConnected = new XmppAsync(mUsername, mPassword,context).execute().get();
            if (isConnected && Utils.getConnection() != null) {
                RegisterConnListeners(Utils.getConnection());
                updateMyProfileImg();

                // connect to all groups
                DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(context);
                adapter.openForRead();
                List<UserDetail> groups = new ArrayList<>();
                adapter.addAllGroups(groups);
                adapter.addPastChatGroups(groups);
                adapter.close();

                for(UserDetail g : groups)
                {
                    CreateXmppMUCSession(g.getGroupTemp());
                }

                return Utils.getConnection();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    } else
        return Utils.getConnection();
}

// get muc chat manager
public static MultiUserChatManager getMucManager() {

    if(mucManager != null)
        return mucManager;

    if (Utils.getConnection() != null) {
        return MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(Utils.getConnection());
    } else {
        if (CreateXmppConnection() != null)
            return MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(Utils.getConnection());
        else {
            Log.v("error", "Some Error Occured");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Cant Connect to Xmpp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }

    }

}

// create muc session and m passing group name - call when you open chat page
public static void CreateXmppMUCSession(String gName)
{
    RegisterGroupChatListeners(gName);
}

// connect to muc if not already connected
public static void RegisterGroupChatListeners(String groupName)
{
    try {
        mStateManager = getChatStateManager();
        multiUserChat = getMUC(groupName);
        //  if(multiUserChat != null) {
        multiUserChat.addMessageListener(new MyMUCMessageListener());
        try {
            if (!multiUserChat.isJoined()) {
                DiscussionHistory discussionHistory = new DiscussionHistory();
                discussionHistory.setMaxStanzas(0);
                multiUserChat.join(new MyPrefrence(context).getUsername().split("@")[0], "123",
                        discussionHistory, SmackConfiguration.getDefaultPacketReplyTimeout());
            }
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //  }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //
    }

}

// get muc 
public static MultiUserChat getMUC(String groupName)
{
  //  Log.v("nick",multiUserChat.getNickname() + " , g = " + groupName);
  //  if(multiUserChat != null && multiUserChat.getRoom().contains(groupName))
  //  {
  //      return multiUserChat;
  //  }

    if (Utils.getConnection() != null) {
        MultiUserChatManager chatManager = getMucManager();
        if (chatManager != null) {
            return chatManager.getMultiUserChat(groupName);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot create Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        if (CreateXmppConnection() != null) {
            MultiUserChatManager chatManager = getMucManager();
            if (chatManager != null) {
                return chatManager.getMultiUserChat(groupName);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot create Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot create Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

and whenever i want to send message i just call this

```
public static Boolean sendMUCChatMsg(Message msg)
{
    if(multiUserChat != null)
        try {
            multiUserChat.sendMessage(msg);

            return true;
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return false;
}
```

Sorry if it looks clumpsy, if I missed any function there let me know, but this is working code which i am using

Comment: can you please tell me how to invite friends?? and GroupChat delete from openfire after sometime.
can you please help.

Comment: Yes, to invite friends check my another answer to this question, i will add now.

for groupchat, I made a background service for xmpp connection, so follow these steps :

Comment: sorry cant type in comment, i will post new answer for this

Answer (score 0):

try this,

I modified your last function

```
static MultiUserChat multiUserChat;
// call this function when you open the chat window
private void CreateGroupConnection(String strGroupID ) {

// Get the MultiUserChatManager
            MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(AbstractXMPPConnection);

            // Create a MultiUserChat using an XMPPConnection for a room
            MultiUserChat multiUserChat = manager.getMultiUserChat(strGroupID + AppWSConstants.XMPP_JID_GROUP_CHAT_SUFFIX);

return multiUserChat;
}

// whenever sending message from chat call this

publilc static void sendMucMessage(Message message){
 if(multiUserChat != null)
 multiUserChat.sendMessage(message);
}
```